# Customizing divs inside a div through CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve something similar to this:
[Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxIM5.png)
, but i encounter some problems.

This is my code from jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4cd77zvk/

HTML code:

```
<div id ="itembox">
    <div id="itempicture">
    </div>
    <div id="iteminfo">
        Info: X
    </br>
        Current price: $
    </br>
        Time until expired: X
    </br>
        Offer avilable for more: X
    </br>
        Place: X
    </div>
    <button class="sendprice" onclick="location.href='#'">Place bid</button>
</div>
```

If you can explain to me please what I'm doing wrong ill be very thankful!

Comment: You don't need to use divs at all the achieve what you have in the image.  Post more details of what you want as your image isn't very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    try this:
   #itembox
    {
        margin-top:5px;
        margin-left: 3px;
        position: relative;

        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 2px;
        height:auto;
        width:230px;

        overflow:hidden;
        float:left;
    }
    #itempicture
    {
        background-image: url('');
        background-color:black;
        height:100px;
    width:100%;

    }
    #iteminfo
    {
        font-family:arial;
        font-size:14px;
      bottom: 0;
        height:auto;
        width:100%;


    }
    #itembox .sendprice
    {
        position: relative;
        height:50px;
        width:100%;
        bottom: 0;
        clear:both;
    }
```

Comment: Just one more thing, i tried to put the height of the itembox back to 290px and i want the button to stick to the buttom, how can i do it? @Anonymous

Comment: happy to help:)

Answer (score 0):

Using `display: inline-flex` brought you on the wrong path.

Comment: yes i figured it out now, i just copied a part of other css project that i'v done without bothering to even look, and then i didn't understand what happened...